# How to fix mypy to allow infer types from dictionary with interfaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

so we have a really easy injector that just fits our needs. Now we want to have type inference, but we are having quite a hard time making it work with mypy. Here you have a minified example reproducing the problem:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Dict

class Interface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass

class Implementation(Interface):
    pass


T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
def get_implementation(interface: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
    dictionary: Dict[Type[T], T] = {Interface: Implementation}
    return dictionary[interface](*args, **kwargs)


implementation = get_implementation(Interface)
```

You can run that code on https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.971&python=3.6. You will get the following error:

```
main.py:15: error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Type[Interface]": "Type[Implementation]"; expected "Type[T]": "T"
main.py:16: error: "object" not callable
main.py:19: error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[Interface]" is expected
```

To be honest, I don't have a clue how to fix them. To me the code seems correct, but clearly mypy doesn't think the same. So any idea how to make this kind of injection type safe?

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through your errors one by one.

---

##### `Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Type[Interface]": "Type[Implementation]"; expected "Type[T]": "T"`

You defined the `get_implementation` function as generic in terms of the type `T` that it will receive as its `interface` argument. That means inside the *body* of the function the type `T` is **bound** to whatever was passed as the `interface` argument.

You then use that type `T` in the annotation of the `dictionary` variable, specifying that its key type shall be `Type[T]`, but then you assign a dictionary to that variable with the key type `Type[Interface]`:

```py
def get_implementation(interface: Type[T], *args, **kwargs) -> T:
    dictionary: Dict[Type[T], T] = {Interface: Implementation}
```

This is wrong because `T` might be bound to something other than `Interface`, when that function is called. It may be called with some subclass `Foo` of `Interface` for example. In that case `T` would resolve to that subclass `Foo` in the function body and the `dictionary` variable's key type would be `Type[Foo]`. This means assigning a dictionary with the key type `Type[Interface]` is an error.

In fact, since you did not even place an upper bound (of say `Interface`) on `T`, you would be free to call `get_implementation` with **literally any type** as the first argument. By calling it with `int` for example, `T` would be bound to `int`, thus only allowing the `dictionary` keys to be the type `int`.

With the value type of that dictionary it is the same deal. But here there is another issue. The dictionary you assign to that variable has a value of type `Type[Implementation]`, but your annotation says the value type should just be `T`. In essence your annotation `Dict[Type[T], T]` expresses that the dictionary values must be **instances** of the classes used as its keys. But `Implementation` is not an instance of `Interface`, it is a subtype/subclass of it.

---

##### `"object" not callable`

Here we are dealing with a consequence of the missing upper bound on `T` as well as the strange annotation of that `dictionary` variable (specifically its value type).

Since `T` can be literally any type (no bound) and the `interface` argument is of type `Type[T]`, the most specific inference a type checker can make about it is that it will be *some* `type` subtype. In other words, the most general type there is.

And an instance of the most general type is simply `object`. Since your `dictionary` is annotated as containing values of that type (i.e. `object`) it is not safe to do `dictionary[some_key](...)`. It is not safe to assume that a value of that dictionary is **callable** because objects are not generally callable.

---

##### `Only concrete class can be given where "Type[Interface]" is expected`

This one is fairly straightforward. Passing around abstract base classes is generally unsafe because they are explicitly not meant to (or simply cannot) be instantiated. You are calling `get_implementation` and passing the ABC `Interface` to it. Types are usually meant to be instantiated (at least when provided as normal function arguments).

---

I can only assume that you discarded a lot of context to make the example minimal, but the code raises a *lot* of questions about what it is you actually try to accomplish here. You used the term "injection" multiple times, but that term is ambiguous (and quite frankly meaningless with this context).

It *looks* a bit like you just have an alternative constructor or some kind of factory for `Interface` subclasses, though that dictionary is *highly* dubious.

If a factory is all you wanted, a working and (somewhat) type safe example might look something like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Type, TypeVar

class Interface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self) -> Any:
        pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Interface)

def get_implementation(interface: Type[T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
    ...
    return interface(*args, **kwargs)

class Implementation(Interface):
    def method(self) -> None:
        print("hi mom")

implementation = get_implementation(Implementation)
reveal_type(implementation)  # Revealed type is "Implementation"
```

The constructor arguments are of course not really safe, but with the **highly** limited typing capabilities of Python 3.6 there is not much we can do about that.

If you provide more context and explain what it is you are trying to accomplish here, I can try and amend this answer to give you a more concrete solution. (You can edit your question and comment here.)

Comment: Hi! Great answer, I have learnt a lot about the typing reading it, so thanks! My main purpose here is to create a service locator with correct type hints. So I have a ton of pairs interface-implementation. Does that add some clarity to my question?