# How to add type hints for a dictionary that maps a class to an instance of that class?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a dictionary, `foo`, that maps a type (class) to an instance of that type:

```py
class Demo:
    pass


foo = {
    int: 5,
    str: "Hi",
    Demo: Demo()
}
```

How can I add type hints to this variable to allow type checkers such as `mypy` or `pyright` to make sure this variable's contents are correct?

I tried to use a type variable:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class Demo:
    pass


foo: dict[type[T], T] = {
    int: 5,
    str: "Hi",
    Demo: Demo()
}
```

But `pyright` simply complains: `Type variable "T" has no meaning in this context`. How can I annotate this variable correctly?

**Edit:**

Here's my use case, which I find hard to type hint. I have a singleton metaclass similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python):

```py
from typing import ClassVar


class Singleton(type):
    _instances: ClassVar[dict[type[?], ?]] = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> ?:
        instance = cls._instances.get(cls)
        if instance is None:
            instance = cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return instance
        name = cls.__name__
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"{name} already created. use {name}.get() to get the {name} instance."
        )

    def get(cls) -> ? | None:
        return cls._instances.get(cls)
```

I found, in general, that type hinting this metaclass is harder than it should be. I can't understand how to add type hints to the attributes and methods of this metaclass in a way that satisfies the type checker and reflects my intentions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix mypy to allow infer types from dictionary with interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075727/how-to-fix-mypy-to-allow-infer-types-from-dictionary-with-interfaces)

Comment: No. I don't have any function or class for this variable. I simply have a variable `foo` which should be annotated as I explained and it appears that type variables don't work for this.

Comment: Write a `typing.Protocol` with the API of `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434302/how-to-annotate-a-dict-of-type-to-function-that-returns-type

Comment: Well, this question first seemed to be obvious and turned out to be a very good case study.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement that with just a dict, but you can create a subclass of dict implementing `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` the way you described.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Any, ClassVar, Self
_T = TypeVar("_T")

class TypeToInstanceDict(dict[type, Any]):

    def __getitem__(self, __key: type[_T]) -> _T:
        return super().__getitem__(__key)

    def __setitem__(self, __key: type[_T], __value: _T):
        return super().__setitem__(__key, __value)
    
    def get(self, __key: type[_T]) -> _T | None:
        return super().get(__key)


    # you can also add 'get()' overloads, 'pop()', 'popitem()' and whatever else
    # interacts with single data points if you want to
```

Your `Singleton` class could look like this then:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances: ClassVar[TypeToInstanceDict] = TypeToInstanceDict()

    def __call__(cls: type[_T], *args, **kwargs) -> _T:
        instance = __class__._instances.get(cls)
        if instance is None:
            instance = __class__._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return instance
        name = cls.__name__
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"{name} already created. use {name}.get() to get the {name} instance."
        )

    def get(cls: type[_T]) -> _T | None:
        return __class__._instances.get(cls)


class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    pass


class FooBar(Singleton):
    pass

FooBar.get()
```

I'd rather suggest you to overwrite `__new__` instead of using a metaclass though:

```
class Singleton:

    _instances: ClassVar[TypeToInstanceDict] = TypeToInstanceDict()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> Self:
        instance = cls._instances.get(cls)
        if instance is None:
            instance = cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
            return instance
        name = cls.__name__
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"{name} already created. use {name}.get() to get the {name} instance."
        )
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # just exists as without it pyright would allow arbitrary args/kwargs
        # because __new__ allows any parameters
        pass
    
    @classmethod
    def get(cls) -> Self | None:
        return cls._instances.get(cls)


class FooBar(Singleton):
    pass
```

Docs:

- [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object): Is the class that's currently defined - injected by the interpreter
- [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): Similar to `__init__` but creates/returns an instance, instead of initialising one.
- [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self): Type variable referring to the current class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about the use case of such a dict, but what might work is the following:

```
from typing import TypedDict


class Demo:
    pass


class Foo(TypedDict):
    int: int
    str: str
    Demo: Demo


foo = Foo(int=5, str="Hi", Demo=Demo())
```

Comment: I can't list all the types that are going to be stored in this dictionary. I need that for **any** type `T`, a mapping of `type[T]` to `T` will be considered valid. So, if someone decides in the future to do `foo[AnotherClass] = AnotherClass(...)`, it will be accepted.
As for the use case, I have a Singleton meta class similar to the one defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python), and it has a dictionary between types and their corresponding singleton instance.

Comment: I added the use case in an edit

Comment: That's indeed a difficult one...What about this?

First define, `T = TypeVar("T")`. Then make your class with a `Generic`. Like this: `class Singleton(type, Generic[T]):`. In this case mypy doesn't throw an error when you do:  `_instances: dict[type[T], T] = {}`.
Of doesn't this work for a Singleton?

Comment: I already tried it. Notice that `_instances` is a class variable since it really belongs to the metaclass and not to any of its instances (classes). That means that type variables are thrown out of the window.